# Child window elements are blocked in Qt C++

Tags: c++, qt

I have three windows: MainWindow, SelectPreset, Preset.
The SelectPreset window is called from the MainWindow window.
And the Preset window is called from the SelectPreset window.
But I can't understand why the Preset window elements are blocked (At the same time, this happens for some reason in Debian, in other systems I did not notice this).

Here's how my files work:

mainwindow.cpp

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) : 
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}
.
.
.
SelectPreset select_preset;
select_preset.setModal(true);
select_preset.exec();
```

selectpreset.cpp

```
SelectPreset::SelectPreset(QWidget *parent) :
    QDialog(parent),
    ui_selectpreset(new Ui::SelectPreset)
{
    ui_selectpreset->setupUi(this);
}
.
.
.
Preset preset;
preset.setModal(true);
preset.exec();
```

preset.cpp

```
Preset::Preset(QWidget *parent) :
    QDialog(parent),
    ui_preset(new Ui::Preset)
{
    ui_preset->setupUi(this);
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
Preset preset(this);
preset.setModal(true);
preset.exec();
```